# How to define a Tuple with named fields in .NET 4.7?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to have a function return a ValueTuple with named fields as opposed to 'Item1', 'Item2', etc.

Looking at the [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples) I have the following function:

```
Public Function MyFunction() as (Success as Boolean, Results as Boolean)
    Return (True, False)
end Function

Dim test = MyFunction()

If test.Success Then
    'Do something with test.Result
End If
```

This compiles, but if I put a breakpoint on the if statement and view 'test', it shows it's fields as 'Item1' and 'Item2'. It also throws the following exception at runtime:

```
System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Success' on type 'ValueTuple(Of Boolean,Boolean)' not found.'
```

Also, the documention only works with 'Option Strict Off' however we have it turned On in our code, and the code does not compile with Option Strict On.

With Option Strict On, I've tried the following:

```
Dim test as ValueTuple(Of Success as Boolean, Results as Boolean) = MyFunction()
```

However it gives a compile time error on 'Success' saying it is not defined.

Do I have the syntax wrong? How can I define a variable to use as the output of that function with named fields while Option Strict On is set?

If relevant, my project is in .NET 4.6.1 but I've added the ValueTuple package using the NuGet package manager.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? I'm not sure about in VB, but at least in C# named tuples require compiler support. If you are using an older version of Visual Studio doesn't doesn't know about named tuples, that could explain why it isn't working for you.

Comment: I'm using 15.9.13 which I believe is the latest version of VS 2017. Would 2019 have better support for it? I didn't realize it had a stable version out yet.

Comment: This code would work as expected even with `Option Strict On`. Leave `Option Infer On`. Of course you need to set `Dim test = MyFunction()` in a method.

Comment: But, why starting a new Project on .Net `4.6.1` when `4.8` is already out. Use at least `4.7.2`. Recommended.

Comment: How come your title says .NET 4.7 while your question says .NET 4.6.1?

Comment: `Dim test as ValueTuple(Of Success as Boolean, Results as Boolean) = MyFunction()` is incorrect and should be `Dim test As (Success as Boolean, Results as Boolean) = MyFunction()`.  You should not need to specify the type though, if you have `Option Infer On`.  I just tried the same code as you and it worked fine in .NET 4.7.2.  I'll test with 4.6 and the NuGet package.

Comment: Just tested with .NET 4.6.1 and the System.ValueTuple package and it worked as expected again.  `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` both `On`.  It still worked with `Option Infer Off` if I specified the type as I mentioned above.

Comment: Works as expected in 4.7.2

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of confusing things going on in your question, but most of it is easy to clear up.

Tuples provide a similar kind of functionality to Anonymous types in the .NET framework, but they are implemented differently, and I think that difference is causing confusion here.

Let's look at this code:

```
Dim x = (Success := True, Results := False)

Dim y = New With {.Success = True, .Results = False}
```

The first is a tuple and the second an anonymous type.

They can both be used in a similar way:

```
Console.WriteLine(x.Success)
Console.WriteLine(y.Success)

Console.WriteLine(x.Results)
Console.WriteLine(y.Results)
```

Under the hood, though, they are constructed differently.

Here is the same code decompiled (as C# as that's all my tool produces):

```
(bool, bool) valueTuple = (true, false);
VB$AnonymousType_0<bool, bool> vB$AnonymousType_ = new VB$AnonymousType_0<bool, bool>(Success: true, Results: false);
Console.WriteLine(valueTuple.Item1);
Console.WriteLine(vB$AnonymousType_.Success);
Console.WriteLine(valueTuple.Item2);
Console.WriteLine(vB$AnonymousType_.Results);
```

Notice that the tuple has properties `Item1` and `Item2` (actually they are fields), but the anonymous type has properties `Success` and `Results`.

**Naming the tuple fields is just compiler trickery!** Reflecting on the type does not return the names used in the source.

Anonymous types do create objects with properties with reflectable names from the source.

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", x.GetType().GetFields().Select(Function(z) z.Name)))
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", y.GetType().GetProperties().Select(Function(z) z.Name)))
```

I get:

```
Item1, Item2
Success, Results
```

The tuple approach allows me to then write this:

```
Dim w As (Apple As Boolean, Banana As Boolean) = x

Console.WriteLine(w.Apple)
Console.WriteLine(w.Banana)
```

You can't do that with anonymous types.

In your question you say that you get a run-time error running your code. I don't get that on my computer. Your first lot of code runs fine.

Comment: Does not work for me with VB 15.5 unfortunately, I only get back Item1, Item2, ....

Comment: @TimothyC.Quinn - With what bit of code?

Comment: Dang, just realized, I was using the standard valueTuple example (first one) and not the AnonymousType (`new With{` ...) example. The AnonymousType is interesting but a bit wordy for my code. Thanks for your excellent post.